# Animation.startNow didn't work on high API Level

Tags: java, android, android-animation

The code which is about Animation (start and cancel, just a simple demo) works on Android API 10, but when I run it on API19, it didn't work, I don't know why? 
anyone who knows why, could you guide me?

```
public class Animation_Act extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button mIdBtnStartAnimation;
    private Button mIdBtnStopAnimation;
    private ImageView mIdIvFlag;

    Animation translateAnimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation_cancel);

        mIdBtnStartAnimation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_btn_startAnimation);
        mIdBtnStopAnimation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_btn_stopAnimation);
        mIdIvFlag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id_iv_flag);

        mIdBtnStartAnimation.setOnClickListener(this);
        mIdBtnStopAnimation.setOnClickListener(this);

        translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 200, 0, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.id_btn_startAnimation:
                translateAnimation.setDuration(3000);
                mIdIvFlag.setAnimation(translateAnimation);
                translateAnimation.startNow();
                break;
            case R.id.id_btn_stopAnimation:
                translateAnimation.cancel();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have checked it is working fine in API 19 (Samsung Tab4), Debug it and Check your logcat if there is any exception or error..

Comment: please clearify: what does not work? Just the animation which is not playing or is your app crashing  or something else?

Comment: @RameshKumar  Thanks for replying . I have debugged and also checked the logcat ,there is no  exception or error output ,so wierd, the animation just  didn't play on API leve 19

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Thanks for replying . Just the animation didn't play ,I couldn't figure it out ,o(╯□╰)o .

Comment: can´t find an issue, there must some other reason elsewhere in your project. What about the gradle file and the includes etc....could you post the gradle?

Comment: @David Use genymotion and add a API 19 virtual device and check on it. weather it is working or not.

Comment: on which device do you have checked against API19?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs thanks  again . I fixed my  code " mIdIvFlag.startAnimation(translateAnimation);", then it works well 。 Thank you so much